Understanding the proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz: Let $M$ be maximal ideal of $R[x_1,...,x_n]$. If $R$ is not G-domain, then $R\cap M\neq 0$
I tried to understand the proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz from the short article written by Prof. R. G. Swan. Then I got stuck in the proof of Theorem 3.1, here's the statement (I also give the relative theorems/definitions):

Theorem 3.1. Let $R$ be a domain and let $M$ be a maximal ideal of the polynomial ring $R[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$. If $R\cap M=0$ then there is a non–zero element $a$ in $R$ such
that $R_a$ is a field and $K = R[X_1, . . . , X_n]/M $ is a finite extension of $R_a$.


Lemma 2.1. A polynomial ring $R[X]$ is never a G–domain.


Corollary 2.3. Let $K$ a field is the integral extension of $R$, then $R$ is a field.


Definition An integral domain $R$ is a G-domain if there exists $a\in R$ such that $R_a=Frac(R)$, where $R_a=R[a^{-1}]$.

The proof is done by doing induction on $n$:
$n=0$ is a trivial case.
Suppose the result holds up to $k\leq n-1$. Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$. Assume $R\cap M=0$, we claim that there exists $a\in R$ such that $R_{a}$ is a field. This shows $R$ is not a $G$-domain.
By Lemma 2.1, $R[x_{1}]$ is not a G-domain, and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x_{1}][x_{2},...,x_{n}]$. By induction hypothesis, $M\cap R[x_{1}]\neq 0$, let $f_{1}=a_{1}x_{1}^{n_{1}}+...\in M\cap R[x_{1}]$. Similarly, we assume $f_{i}=a_{i}x_{i}^{n_{i}}+r_{i,n_{i-1}}x_{i}^{n_{i}-1}...\in M\cap R[x_{i}]$ with $a_{i}\neq 0$ for all $i$. Let $a=\prod a_{i}\in R-\{0\}$. Let $y_{i}=x_{i}+M\in K$, since $f_{i}+M=0+M$ and $R\cap M=0$, we have
$$a_{i}y_{i}^{n_{i}}+r_{i,n_{i-1}}y_{i}^{n_{i}-1}+...=0\Rightarrow y_{i}^{n_{i}}+\dfrac{r_{i,n_{i-1}}}{a_{i}}y_{i}^{n_{i}-1}+...=0$$
Note that the fraction with denominator $a_{i}$ is in $R_{a}$, thus $y_{i}$ is integral over $R_{a}$ for each $i$. Also note that $R$ is trivially integral over $R_{a}$ (for $r\in R$, $r-\frac{r}{1}=0$). Since integral elements form a subring, $K$ is integral over $R_{a}$. Then by Corollary 2.3, $R_a$ is a field.
I don't understand the parts in bold. We need to show $R_a$ is a subring of $K$ first before using the Corollary. However, I couldn't find any isomorphism to make $R_a$ to be a subring of $K$. Hence I was wondering whether this whole argument is legal or not. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The composition $R\to R[X_1,\dots,X_n]\to R[X_1,\dots,X_n]/M=K$ is injective since $M\cap R=0$. In this way $R$ becomes a subring of $K$ and therefore any (non-zero) localization becomes a subring of $K$ as well.

Sorry, why $R$ is a subring of $K$ implies $R_a$ is a subring of $K$?

If $R$ is a subring of a field $K$ and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$ not containing $0$, then $S^{-1}R$ can be identified with the subring ${rs^{-1}\mid r\in R,s\in S}$ of $K$.

Thanks for your response, but I still don't understand...Why $S^{-1}R$ can be "identified" as the subring of $K$? Why ${rs^{-1} | r\in R, s\in S}\subseteq K$?

What is your definition of the localization $S^{-1}R$?

Just like the definition in any textbook? I'm not sure if this is what you mean: Since $R$ is a subring of a field, for any $s\in S$ we can find $s^{-1}\in K$. Hence every element $\frac{r}{s}\in S^{-1}R={\frac{r}{s} | r\in R, s\in S}$ can be identified as $rs^{-1}\in K$?

Often the localization is defined as some quotient of $R\times S$ by a suitable equivalence relation and then $\frac rs$ denotes an equivalence class. This satisfies a certain universal property. The inclusion map $R\to K$ extends by this universal property to an injective map $S^{-1}R\to K$ and in this way we can identify the localization with a subring of $K$ (and this subring consists of elements of the form $rs^{-1}$).
